# Python Program to extract sections of a txt file from a list of words

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing, data-extraction

I want a python program that should print each section of a text file.
The section is defined by the keyword found from a list of words and starts with the line at which the keyword is present and ends at that line at which next section starts.
For e.g. Consider the following text file

```
word1
abcdef
ghis jsd sjdhd jshj
word2
dgjgj dhkjhf
khkhkjd
word23
dfjkg fjidkfh
word5
diow299 udhgbhdi
jkdkjd
word89
eyuiywiou299092    
word3
...
...
...
```

**Required Output** by the program is:

```
Sections Found: [word1, word2, word3, word5, word89]

**********word1--SECTION**********
line 1: word1
line 2: abcdef
line 3: ghis jsd sjdhd jshj

**********word2--SECTION**********
line 4: word2
line 5: dgjgj dhkjhf
line 6: khkhkjd

**********word3--SECTION**********
line 14: word 3
line 15: ....

''' Suppose word4 is not found in the txt file then it should continue and move to next word found''' 
**********word5--SECTION**********
line 9: word5
line 10: diow299 udhgbhdi
line 11: jkdkjd

...
...
...
...

'''Continue till the end of list of words '''
```

## Approach:

list_of_words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'word6', ....]

find the start_line for each word in list_of_word and store them in a list

then find end_line for each word by sorting the list so that it is easy to find the greatest near end line for a word

then print the section found with their line no.:  line_in_text_file

Code Used for getting Line Number: (How to create a variable for each n in list_of_words)

```
for n in list_of_words:
    with open(file_txt, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
        data_file = f.readlines()
    for num, lines in enumerate(data_file, 1):
        if n in lines:
            start_line = num
        else:
            continue
```

Code used to find the nearest number greater than n_start_line(val) the start_line_list:

```
def closest(array_list, val):
    array_list1 = [j for j in array_list if j > val]
    array_list1.sort()
    return array_list1[0]
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @Богдан Опир 
I have added the code,

Answer (score 0):

pyparsing has a generator function `scanString` that will yield the matched tokens and start and end locations of the match. Using the start location, call pyparsing's `lineno` method to get the matched line number.

```
import pyparsing as pp

marker = pp.oneOf("word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word23")

txt = """\
word1
abcdef
ghis jsd sjdhd jshj
word2
dgjgj dhkjhf
khkhkjd
word23
dfjkg fjidkfh
word5
diow299 udhgbhdi word2
jkdkjd
word89
eyuiywiou299092    
word3
"""

previous = None
for t, s, e in (pp.LineStart() + marker | pp.StringEnd()).scanString(txt):
    current_line_number = pp.lineno(s, txt)
    if t:
        current = t[0]
        if previous is not None:
            print(previous, "ended on line", current_line_number - 1)
        print("found", current, "on line", current_line_number)
        previous = current
    else:
        if previous is not None:
            print(previous, "ended on line", current_line_number)
```

Prints:

```
found word1 on line 1
word1 ended on line 3
found word2 on line 4
word2 ended on line 6
found word23 on line 7
word23 ended on line 8
found word5 on line 9
word5 ended on line 13
found word3 on line 14
word3 ended on line 15
```

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: No, this doesn't work if the word1 consists of 2 words or more. e.g word1 = 'email id'
Therefore I prefer to use a list of strings list_of_keywords = ['word1', 'word2', ......]
I guess you have understood what i mean to say here.

Comment: oneOf will accept a sequence (list, tuple, generator, dict, etc.) of strings or a single space-delimited string. The approach is the same. You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Did some modification in the code and stored the result in a dictonary for key = keywords_found  & value = line no. at which they are.
Can't figure out how to store values for the line no. at which each section ends. Can you help me with that?

```found_keywords_dict = {}

for t, s, e in (pp.LineStart() + marker).scanString(txt):

      found_keywords_dict[t[0]] = pp.lineno(s, txt)
```

I want to store the end_line_no. so that i can print the lines between start_line_no. and end_line_no.

Comment: Can you infer from the presence of a keyword that the previous keyword's section ends on the previous line? Keep track of the previous keyword, and update its entry in your dict using `found_keywords_dict[prev_keyword] = (found_keywords_dict[prev_keyword], pp.lineno(s, txt) - 1)`

Comment: See edits where matched keyword is saved in `previous` for reference when the next keyword is matched. Also needed to add a match at the end of the input string, so that the final end line number could be found.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcG, it worked. I converted the output into 2 dictionaries. One for start_line and one for end_line. I want to ask you, what does if t: line mean ? Also when i was running it on actual data there is some issue that I face. e.g. wordX = "email" and wordY = "emails id"; wordX appears before wordY in pp.oneOf() and the text consists of .... emails id .... then the code considers "email" instead of "emails id". can anything be helpful in this, so that "email id" is considered without manually reformatting the list_of_keywords?

Comment: You can learn more about what `if t:` is doing if you put `print(t)` on the line before it. Or take it out and see what happens (change to `if True:` intsead of `if t:`). As for oneOf handling of longer or shorter elements, I do not reproduce this issue. Post as a new question and show the oneOf expression you are using that is giving you trouble (you can cut it down to just "emails" and "emails id".

Comment: I can't cut it down to  just "emails" and "emails id", intstead of that it could readlines instead of reading words from txt, because the list_of_keywords will be always on a new line without anyother word